# How to set permission without command summon?

Tags: discord.js

Here is an idea of the code that would work in my ideal world:

```
client.guild.cache.get(`${server_ID}`).roles.cache.get(`${role_ID}`).setPermissions(123456789);
```

But, as expected, it doesn't work.
(`Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`)
I researched here, on a lot of forum and website but I couldn't figured out... Do you have any idea ?

*If you think I could improve the question, tell me*

Comment: Can you show your error?

Comment: Will you laught if I tell you that, thanks to your request, I forgot the "s" at the end of "guild"... IT NOW WORKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the s at the end of guild (I now hate myself)

`` client.guilds.cache.get(`${server_ID}`).roles.cache.get(`${role_ID}`).setPermissions.setPermissions(0123456789) ``